# Проблема с реализацией возможностей ofstream,istream в файле .cpp

Tags: c++-cli

Есть заголовочный файл `methods.h` ,с таким содержимым

```
#ifndef methods_H
#define methods_H

void created(int Nt, int Nx);
inline double fn(int T, double x);
inline double u0(int T, double x);
inline double u1(int T, double a, int xmin, double t);
inline double u2(int T, double a, int xmax, double t);
void calculatedifnet(int xmin, double hx, double ht, double a, int Nx, int Nt, int T);
void writeinto(int Nx, int Nt);
#endif methods_H
```

Есть файл `methods.cpp` с таким содержимым

```
#include "methods.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

double** wht;

void created(int Nt, int Nx)
{
    // используется поле
    wht = new double *[Nt];
    // тут i - локальная переменная (имеется объявление int)
    for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
        wht[i] = new double[Nx];
}

inline double fn(int T, double x)
{
    if (x >= 0)
        return T;
    return 0;
}

inline double u0(int T, double x)
{
    return fn(T, x);
}

inline double u1(int T, double a, int xmin, double t)
{
    return fn(T, xmin - a * t);
}

inline double u2(int T, double a, int xmax, double t)
{
    return fn(T, xmax - a * t);
}


void calculatedifnet(int xmin, double hx, double ht, double a, int Nx, int Nt, int T)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
    {
        wht[0][i] = u0(T, xmin + i*hx);//Заполнение начальных условий xmin
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < Nt - 1; j++)//Вывод устойчивой схемы
    {
        wht[j + 1][0] = u1(T, a, xmin, j*ht);
        for (int i = 1; i < Nt; i++)
        {
            double dudx = (wht[j][i] - wht[j][i - 1]) / hx;
            wht[j + 1][i] = -a * dudx * ht + wht[j][i];
        }
    }
}

void writeinto(int Nx, int Nt)//Запись в файл
{
    String^ fileName = "results.txt";
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
    for (int j = 0; j < Nt; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
        {
            sw->Write("{0:0.#} ", wht[j][i]); //горизонтальная 12, вертикальная 10.
        }
        sw->WriteLine();
    }
    sw->Close();
}
```

На строках ниже компилятор ругается на якобы необъявленные идентификаторы `String^,StreamWriter`

```
String^ fileName = "results.txt";
StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
```

Но ведь по идее подключенные `include`-ы должны были дать возможность работать с записью в файл.
Плюс всё-таки в `.cpp` файл прописывается реализация методов,я её прописал,но что-то пошло не так.

Comment: @Abyx но там у меня подключены fstream,ostream

Answer (score 0):

Собственно исправил на следующий код

```
   void writeinto(int Nx, int Nt)//Запись в файл
{   
    ofstream fout("results.txt", ios::out);
    for (int j = 0; j < Nt; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
            {
                fout<<wht[j][i]<<" "; //горизонтальная 12, вертикальная 10.
            }
            fout << '\n';
        }
    cout << endl;
    fout.close();
}
```

И всё стало компилироваться и сохранятся

Comment: Лучше б вы открыли пространство имён `using namespace System::IO;`. А нативный `fstream` вообще уберите.